# Unable to add Xamarin.Essentials package to project

Tags: xamarin.forms, cross-platform, nuget-package, xamarin.essentials

I'm unable to add Xamarin.Essentials package to my cross platform project through 
**Manage NuGet packages** after processing it shows the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin.Essentials package still does not support Android Support Libraries v28

So at the moment, your best option is to downgrade support libraries to 27.0.0 or wait until they do a new release to support v28

You can track their [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/pull/669).

Comment: how can I downgrade my support libraries ? can you please guide ? Thanks!

Comment: @HashirMalik try to uninstall and then install the v27.0.0